# Error faces not defined when trying to draw box around face and body

Tags: python, opencv, face-recognition

i get a error when i try to draw a box around my face and body

```
while True:
    _, frame = cap.read()

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
    bodies = body_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
 # draws box on faces
    for (x, y, width, height) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + width, y + height), (255, 0, 0,), 3)

    for (x, y, width, height) in bodies:
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + width, y + height), (255, 0, 0,), 3)
```

error:
for (x, y, width, height) in faces:
NameError: name 'faces' is not defined

Comment: Debug your code. Draw boxes only if `faces` is not empty.

Comment: `if faces: for (x, y, width, height) in faces: .....`

Comment: so like this if faces: for (x, y, width, height) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + width, y + height), (255, 0, 0,), 3)

Comment: Yes. And do the same for `bodies` also.